# Facebook API not returning media source any more, how to get video links?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Sometime in the past month or so my app broke because I can no longer retrieve videos from the Facebook accounts I have access to. I use the [https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{page-id}/published_posts](https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/%7Bpage-id%7D/published_posts) endpoint to get all the posts and I include the attachments to those posts. Here is a video post from the response:

```
{
   full_picture: "https://scontent-sof1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/52285035_2234305973503753_1707934143716786176_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ad6a45&_nc_eui2=AeFnVEo3_0GBN3Z0ArKuyCC4PTctiml3Kak9Ny2KaXcpqfKpYLmuK7xAuPYTdTHOo-Rl5ZFJIsozhkhH2MI5T0OD&_nc_ohc=ZGkoZa1Nb98AX-by7TS&_nc_ht=scontent-sof1-1.xx&edm=APyxFHYEAAAA&oh=cf6f755c7a512dd74540343473b8e015&oe=611FF12B",
   picture: "https://scontent-sof1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/s130x130/52285035_2234305973503753_1707934143716786176_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ad6a45&_nc_eui2=AeFnVEo3_0GBN3Z0ArKuyCC4PTctiml3Kak9Ny2KaXcpqfKpYLmuK7xAuPYTdTHOo-Rl5ZFJIsozhkhH2MI5T0OD&_nc_ohc=ZGkoZa1Nb98AX-by7TS&_nc_ht=scontent-sof1-1.xx&edm=APyxFHYEAAAA&oh=f8f27b8ad553f2099ade862250868929&oe=611FDA5A",
   message: "Plurato Sailfin u HRT-ovoj emisiji More",
   permalink_url: "https://www.facebook.com/239543599886541/posts/563119407528957/",
   created_time: "2019-03-10T15:58:31+0000",
   attachments: {
      data: [
      {
         media: {
            image: {
               height: 406,
               src: "https://scontent-sof1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/s720x720/52285035_2234305973503753_1707934143716786176_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ad6a45&_nc_eui2=AeFnVEo3_0GBN3Z0ArKuyCC4PTctiml3Kak9Ny2KaXcpqfKpYLmuK7xAuPYTdTHOo-Rl5ZFJIsozhkhH2MI5T0OD&_nc_ohc=ZGkoZa1Nb98AX-by7TS&_nc_ht=scontent-sof1-1.xx&edm=APyxFHYEAAAA&oh=ad3c1789fa9e72210e2bcaf23b39ea9c&oe=61208A3C",
               width: 720
            }
         },
         media_type: "video",
         url: "https://www.facebook.com/HRTvijesti/videos/1271130086359640/"
      }
      ]
   },
   id: "239543599886541_563119407528957"
},
```

It used to be that I would get a link to an actual video. I looked through my code and the part that extracts the url is:

```
const getFileUrl = (apiResult: Services.FacebookService.ApiPostListResponse) => {
    if (apiResult.attachments) {
        if (apiResult.attachments.data[0].media.source) return apiResult.attachments.data[0].media.source
        else if (isYoutubeLink(apiResult.attachments.data[0].url)) {
            return getYoutubeLink(apiResult.attachments.data[0].url, true)
        } else return apiResult.attachments.data[0].media.image.src
    } else return apiResult.full_picture
}
```

Apparently there used to be a "source" property under media but I can't seem to access that any more. I need a link which I can use to paly a video in a HTML video element. Is there any way of getting such a link now? I couldn't find it by browsing the documentation or by playing with the graph explorer. The attachments.data.url field is a link to a video but not to a video file, just a page that has a video inside it and I can't use that.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the above issue. I am also not able to get the source property

Comment: I am no longer maintaining the API that used this but I had a lot of problems getting the source consistently. Don't take my word for this but, if I recall correctly, FB changed its API so it SOMETIMES returns the source, depending on a bunch of things. This behavior might have changed again in the meantime. I ended up not using the source property as I couldn't rely on it.